# Connect clients in server-client system

Tags: .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, client-server, chat

I have a multithreaded server-client system where clients chat with the server and receive the sent message back, but only client-to-server way of communication. I want to make it client-to-client. The thing is that I don't know how to distinguish between the clients and perhaps attach each-other's network streams to one-another.

I don't want to make it for 2 clients only, but to make it in a generic way so I can connect i.e. 6 clients, so that every second connected client finds the previous connected one.

I have thought of a `TcpClient[]` array where I store the clients objects after their connection is accepted, but then I just can't figure out how to distinguish between them and attach them to one-another.

Here is the code of the server class:

```
class TheServer
{
    private TcpListener tcpListener;
    private Thread threadListener;
    TheMessage msg;
    public TcpClient[] clientList = new TcpClient[100];
    private int n = 0;

    public void StartServer()
    {
        try
        {
            this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
            this.threadListener = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
            this.threadListener.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Local end point: " + tcpListener.LocalEndpoint);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private void ListenForClients()
    {
        this.tcpListener.Start();

        while(true)
        {
            // block until a client has connected to the server
            TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            if (n == 0)
            {
                clientList[0] = client;
            }
            else
            {
                n++;
                clientList[n] = client;
            }

            // create thread to handle communication with connected client
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
            clientThread.Start(clientList[n]);

        }
    }

    private void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream stm = tcpClient.GetStream();
        msg = new TheMessage();

        while (true)
        {
            Byte[] bSize = new Byte[sizeof(Int32)];
            stm.Read(bSize, 0, bSize.Length);

            Byte[] bData = new Byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(bSize, 0)];
            stm.Read(bData, 0, bData.Length);

            msg = XmlRefactorServer.ByteArrayToObject<TheMessage>(bData);
            String str = msg.Message;
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            stm.Flush();

            // send back to client
            msg.Message = str;
            Byte[] bDataBack = XmlRefactorServer.ObjectToByteArray<TheMessage>(msg);

            // NetworkStream stm2 = ------> perhaps here should get the second client stream ?!

            Byte[] bSizeBack = BitConverter.GetBytes(bDataBack.Length);

            stm2.Write(bSizeBack, 0, bSizeBack.Length);
            stm2.Write(bDataBack, 0, bDataBack.Length);
            stm2.Flush();

        }

        tcpClient.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Checkout this tutorial which uses a network library to achieve what you are after, http://www.networkcomms.net/creating-a-wpf-chat-client-server-application/. Disclaimer: I'm a developer for this library.